Best approach to enqueue long-running run jobs?
I have the following scenario:
Front-end -> Cloud Run Service on serverless mode.
Based on the user action, it will call a long running and parameterized process, which can take more than one hour to complete.
Important: I CAN'T have two of this process running at same time, for data conflict reasons. I have to enqueue these processes.
What is the best approach to do that on GCP?

You can use Cloud Task to enqueue your process and set a maxConcurrentDispatches to 1. More detail here https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/configuring-queues

Yes, I thought about using tasks, but from what I understand, it only calls one enpoint, and needs to be synchronized with processing (the request can take more than 1 hour to respond). Google Cloud does not allow you to make a call to run a Job and wait with a single http call, and Run Service has a maximum timeout of 60 minutes. How can I make a workaround for this?

Understood... In that case you can imagine something different. You can persist your event with a timestamp (in firestore for instance). Then, you must have a process that iterate over this collection on Firestore and trigger the job in sequence. I imagine Cloud Workflow to achieve it.

I was thinking, based on your idea, it would be a good pattern if, when I have to run my Job, I check to see if there is any job already running. If there is, I persist my event in firestore (or other database technology) and, at the end of the running job, check if there is an event to be executed. If there is, I would start another job, and continue in that workflow until I have executed all of my events. With this design, I would not use Cloud Workflow or Tasks, just a queue in database/firestore based on events

Yes, you can imagine different pattern like this. Take care of race condition, but what you describe should work

Thanks guillaume, I'll try this pattern
